# How to change HTML title in PHP without breaking the XHTML markup validation?

Tags: php, validation, title, xhtml

Here is the structure of the web site:

**PHP index file**

```
//my class for analyzing the PHP query
$parameter = new LoadParameters();

//what this does is it accesses the database
//and according to the query, figures out what should be
//loaded on the page
//some of the things it sets are:
//    $parameter->design -  PHP file which contains the design
//                          HTML code of the page
//    $parameter->content - Different PHP file which should be loaded
//                          inside the design file
$parameter->mysqlGetInfo($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

//load the design file
include($parameter->design);
```

**PHP design file**

Just the generic structure. Obviously it has a lot more design elements.

```
<html>
  <head>
     ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
       //this loads the content into the design page
       include($parameter->content);
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Question**

So here is the problem I experience. The `$parameter->content` file is a dynamic PHP file, meaning the content also changes according to the query.

For instance if I have a image pages with queries like `?img=1` and `?img=2`, my `LoadParameter` class will only look at the `img` part of the query and will know that the content of the page should be `image.php`. `image.php` however will look at the query again and figure out exactly what image to load.

This causes issues for me because I want to have a different `<title></title>` for different images. So my solution was just to set the `<title></title>` element in the content page. This works but it breaks the XHTML markup validation at [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/) because it makes the structure of the site to be the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
     ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <title>sometitle</title>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

And having `<title></title>` within `<body></body>` is not allowed.

So how can I change the title without breaking the XHTML markup validation?

***Note***: I can't use javascript because then Search engines would not be able to see the title of the page. I need to do it directly in PHP.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue.

I changed the PHP design to something like:

```
//get the content PHP file
//inside the file I set the following variables
//which are used below:
//$parameter->title - the string which contains the title
//$parameter->html - the string which contains the HTML content
include($parameter->content);

//string which will contain the html code of the whole page
$html = <<<EndHere
<html>
  <head>
      <title>
EndHere;
//add title
$html .= $parameter->title;
$html .= <<<EndHere
      </title>
  </head>
  <body>
EndHere;
//add the content of the page
$html .= $parameter->html;
$html .= <<<EndHere
  </body>
</html>
EndHere;

//output the html
echo $html;
```

And here is the basic structure of the Content PHP file. Since the only page which can possibly include the file is the my design page, I can reference `$parameter` in it.

```
//set the title
$parameter->title = "sometitle";

//set the content HTML
$parameter->html = "some HTML here";
```

It's not a very clean solution but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

why not do a second include to perform the title in the proper place?

```
<html>
    <head>
     <?php
       inlcude($parameter->title);
     ?>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    //this loads the content into the design page
       include($parameter->content);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the PHP code so that you can do something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title><? print($parameter->title); ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
       //this loads the content into the design page
       include($parameter->content);
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The title is determined in $parameter->content so can't print the title before I include $parameter->content

Comment: What does the contents of $paremeter->content look like? So I can see whether there is another solution? On a side note I think the design of the code does not fit your needs. If I were you I would first think about what I would like to do before designing the PHP code. This prevents lots of headaches at a later phase of development / maintaining / scaling / etc.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. I actually ended up changing the structure quite a bit to be able to make this word. $parameter->content was a php file which contained the HTML code of the content.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move all of the `<head>` code into a 'common function' called something like html_head($title) and then have it put the title where it belongs.

Then simply call that function from within the pages and it's fixed.

Don't forget to include the `<body>` tag in that function, otherwise it won't work!

Elaborating ;)

```
function html_head($title) {?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><?=$title?></title>
            <!-- Put whatever you want... here! -->
        </head>
        <body>
<?}
```

Then in $parameter->content, call html_head("Title")

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if $parameter->content could be included without displaying its HTML code, but instead have a $parameter->display (or similar) function that displays the HTML code. That way, you can include the PHP code at the beginning of the file and not worry about being unable to access the title.

```
<?php
  require_once($parameter->content);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title><?php echo $parameter->title; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
       echo $parameter->display;
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```